# Stuck with Ruby on Code Academy

Tags: ruby

I am doing Code Academy The Refactor Factory: Less is More (Exercise 4) module. Here are the instructions for the module:

> Less is More Great work! This code looks better already.
>
> We can remove even more, however. Recall that Ruby will implicitly
>   (that is, automatically) return the value of the last expression it
>   evaluates. There's one return statement in this code that we can
>   change from explicit to implicit!
>
> Instructions Find the unnecessary return statement and remove it.
>
> Hint: it's the last one! This is because we may want to return early
>   if the input isn't a positive number, and we can't return early unless
>   we explicitly use the return keyword.

I tried to remove the last `return` statement and each of the others, and I get an error. Can anyone offer any suggestions?

```
$VERBOSE = nil    # We'll explain this at the end of the lesson.
require 'prime'   # This is a module. We'll cover these soon!

def first_n_primes(n)

  return "n must be an integer." unless n.is_a? Integer

  return "n must be greater than 0." if n <= 0

  prime_array ||= []

  prime = Prime.new
  for num in (1..n)
    prime_array.push(prime.next)
  end
  return prime_array
end

first_n_primes(10)
```

Comment: Have you removed the entire last statement or just `return` in the statement? The former would not work.

Comment: `for num in (1..n)` etc. is not idiomatic Ruby at all. `require 'prime'; Prime.first(10)` is.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `return` from `return prime_array` should work.